# Is internal redirect visible to client php

Tags: php, http, cakephp, redirect

Consider the user opens a page(mainly submits a form to) `page1.php`, then in that file, after some actions, there is a redirect to page `page_internal.php`, where some conditions are checked and finally it redirects to either `page2.php` or `page3.php`. So, the user initially requests a page `page1.php` and finally lands on `page2.php` or `page3.php`, he does not really see the `page_internal.php`, but is that redirect somehow visible to the client? For example, lets say I use unsecure `http` protocol, if in my `page1.php` file I make a redirect to

```
page_internal.php?q=some_sensitive_data
```

can this `some_sensitive_data` be visible to(be accessed by) client, or that internal request is "happening server side" and only final page is sent to the browser. For Page1, 2 and 3 it does not matter to be secure, just that one internal redirect matters.

**update**

ok lets just forget about submit for a moment, simply

- 1) user opens page1.php in the browser.
- 2) inside the code of that page I redirect  to `page_internal.php?q=some_sensitive_data`
- 3) in
  page_internal.php , checking some conditions I redirect the user to
  page3 or page4.
- 4) all is done through http, qsn: can the client see some_sensitive_data

**update**

qsn2: how to handle this part without using session in cakephp.

Thanks

Comment: If it's fast enough, a normal user won't see it, but e.g. with Firefox's Network Tool you could see what pages are being loaded. It's not possible to hide the fact that there is some intermediary page to a user who wants to know. Best would be to `include` PHP code into another PHP file to hide implementation details.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this? `page1.php` has form that submits, and based on conditions, the result is `page2.php` or `page3.php`?

Comment: @VukStanković, I updated, lemme know if it makes sense

Comment: If you don't want the client to see `q` data, store it inside `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @hjpotter92, actually I had considered that, but session has its security things as well

Comment: You don't *redirect* to `page_internal.php`. You **include** it, execute the code you wanted and then output the result to the user. Anything happening on the client side is visible to the user. It's highly unlikely that a regular computer user will notice the redirect you wanted to do initially, but someone like me will. And I will abuse your system, purely because of the fact it's not a proper design. And there are many people like me out there, so you need to protect yourself as good as you can - and redirecting isn't proper decision.

Comment: @N.B., thanks for ur comment, that is why I asked the qsn to be sure what im doing is not a bad idea. the point is I cant just include the file. I asked the qsn with a general approach to get the idea. I cant including cause im using a cakephp framework: though I could create component in this case, but it is not the best way either in my situation

Comment: If you're using CakePHP, you don't have to include the file itself. You handle things using OOP. Depending on user input, create an object that handles working with that data and depending on result, output different pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you redirect via `header('Location: .../page_internal.php')` then your redirect will be visible to the client. Depending on the speed of your server the url will only be shown very shortly in the url.

But any recording of browsing history, i.e. Chrome Dev Tools will record the call to `page_internal.php` just normally.

---

Some frameworks allow the internal processing of request, by internally forwarding to a request handler instead of forcing the client to make another request:

Use the dispatcher in **CakePHP** instead to use an internal request:

```
$dispatcher = new Dispatcher(); 
$request = new CakeRequest('/pages/internal'); 
$request->data = array('q' => 'some_sensitive_data'); 
$response = new CakeResponse(); 
$dispatcher->dispatch( $request, $response );
```

---

Same can be accomplised in the **Zend Framework**:

```
$this->forward(
  'action', 
  'controller', 
  'module', 
  array(
    'q' => 'some_sensitive_data'
  )
);
```

Comment: `If you redirect via`, is there other way so I can do it and it wont be visible to the client ? thanks

Comment: As mentioned by @ljacqu you should delegate your logic in another file and include it as needed. The conditional was meant to be, if you're not already using a framework, i.e. Zend Framework has a `$request->redirect()` and a `$request->forward` call, the later would not force the client to make the call, but all internal processing would look like a new has been made.

Comment: actually I am using cakephp, but AFAIK there is no forwarding in there. Though I can handle creating component, but there r other issues associated with that. tks

Comment: CakePHP doesn't have forwarding included, but you can use the Dispatcher's `dispatch()` method to do something similar, will add it to my answer.

Comment: Kevin, ur solution worked, just had to change a little, I edited ur answer. please see if it is ok, and I will accept the answer. tks

Comment: What was the change you had to make, can you elaborate?

Comment: sure, this:  $d = new Dispatcher();
  $request = new CakeRequest('/pages/internal');
  $request->data = array('q' => 'some_sensitive_data');
  $response = new CakeResponse();
  
  $d->dispatch(
   $request,
   $response
  );
dispatch params should be objects rather than arrays. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a redirect or any other form of client controlled mechanism to transport sensitive or otherwise data from one point of the server to another is both insecure and unnecessary.

You can persist this information purely on the server side using the session of the client.

This does not mean the data has to specifically belong in the session, something in the session can direct the server what to look for, such as an ID of a database table, or the name of a file.

Answer (score 1):

Client cannot see what appends on you server.
If you simply **forward** actions between scripts it's invisible from the outside.

Client only sees **redirects**. ie : returning a different page than the requested one

He sees his **request** : get page1.php

And your **response** : Location:http://example.com/page2.php

- **Forward** between script : **invisible from outside**
- **Redirect** between pages :: **visible from outside**

Edit:

Seeing you edit which explains your process, What you need is not forwarding, it's some knowing of how to keep track of sensitives datas.

As said in comments, the **session** is made for this. Only server can see those datas.

Ask another question for this.